# no reservation or no reservations on invitation?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am sending one invitation out for 3 events. The planners for two events would like for people to make a reservation for each of those events with their reply. So next to those events, there is wording that a reservation is requested ("reservation is requested with your reply"). Please note the singular "reservation".

For the third event, the planner does not need or want folks to make reservations. So should the wording be "no reservation needed" or "no reservations needed"? Or can it be either way?

Answer (score 2):

The correct form is:

> No reservation needed.

Because you're addressing the person (or persons) whom you are inviting (through a single invitation). So, there is no need for a reservation (a reservation can be made for one or more people) for that group (or person).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

> 1. [reservation](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reservation?q=reservation):[count noun] an arrangement whereby something, especially a seat or room, is reserved for a particular person: do you have a reservation?
> 2. [Subject very agreement](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp): If there are multiple events, each requiring its own request for reservation, then you would use *reservations*. Else, if its just one event, then go ahead and use *reservation* irrespective whether the invitation is going to a group of people or just one person.